# Reverse search is not working on mysql terminal on my mac

Tags: terminal, mysql

I was using the mysql in ubuntu terminal. Reverse search was working fine on my ubuntu terminal. Recently I switched to mac, on mac terminal reverse search works fine normally but when I logged in to mysql the reverse search was not working.

Please suggest some answers I will be using reverse search frequently.

Reverse search is a bash functionality where you search your command history on the fly. More on reverse search can be found [here](https://lifehacker.com/278888/ctrl%252Br-to-search-and-other-terminal-history-tricks)

Comment: What do you mean by „reverse search“?

Comment: Presumably Ctrl+R in bash? I have no idea what the problem could be (I don’t use bash or mySQL) but the default bash that comes with macOS is a long way behind the latest. Potentially upgrading using Homebrew (`brew install bash`) might fix the problem you’re seeing?

Comment: @nohillside You can find what is reverse search here https://lifehacker.com/278888/ctrl%252Br-to-search-and-other-terminal-history-tricks

Comment: In this case once you call mysql it is responsible for the keyboard not bash so we need to know how mysql was compiled and does it include the correct keyboard handling

Answer (score 1):

Reverse search as triggered by <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> is a functionality provided by `bash` and which searches within the shell's command history. Once you start `mysql` you rely on the keyboard combinations available there, you can't use the `bash` shortcuts while `mysql` is running.

If you want to use reverse search with `mysql` you need a version with `readline` support compiled into it.